# Magento 2 Admin Login Error Could not create an acl object: Role '5' not found

Tags: magento2

When logging into the admin section of my Magento 2.2.2 installation I'm getting the error:

""0":"Could not create an acl object: Role '5' not found","1":"#0 /var/www/magento/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Acl/Builder/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Acl\Builder->getAcl()"

I get the same error if I run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from cli.

The Role '5' portion of the error message I think refers to a role_id in the authorization_role table.  There is a row in the table with that role_id so I'm not sure what's triggering the error.

How do I debug and resolve this?

Answer (score 6):

Delete `var/cache`, `var/page_cache`, `var/di`, `generated/` directories and run `setup:upgrade` command.

This will resolve the issue.

Comment: Why God, why Magento has to be so nonsense when it comes to error messages

Answer (score 1):

> **Flush Magento Cache**
>
> - Open Terminal
> - Go to your Magento root directory
>
>   ```
>   cd /path/to/your/magento/folder
>   ```
> - Run the following command:
>
>   ```
>   php bin/magento cache:flush
>   ```